# Looking for land value data for anywhere in North America especially for Florida

Tags: data-request, geospatial, land, north-america

I am researching on road alignment optimization. The research goal is to find least cost road alignment between two given points, considering highway codes. One of the major costs which needs to be considered, is right-of-way cost. To present the methodology in a case study, i need actual land value data or estimated land value or average land value for different land categories. Data for Florida have higher priority than anywhere else for me, since i have other needed data for my research for Florida. Any recommendation or introducing nongeospatial data could be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parcel data in the state of Florida is typically open and available.  Assessed values can be used but this isn't actual home values or cost of land for ROW.  That's a very different thing.

1) https://www.fgdl.org

2) https://geodata.myflorida.com/datasets/parcels-1